# What is the big difference or usage of SQLiteStatement and SQLiteDatabase CRUD methods?

Tags: java, android, mobile

```
insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
return insertStmt.executeInsert();
```

*and the other:*

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("name", name);
return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```